# Calculating the sum of differences between two columns in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, sum, relational-database

I'm attempting to calculate the sum of the differences between the 'from' and 'to' columns in the 'absences' table, but I'm encountering an error.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'absences.hours_difference' in
> 'field list'

```
$classesAbsences = Classes::withSum([
    'absences' => function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `from`, `to`) AS hours_difference');
    }
], 'absences.hours_difference')
    ->get();
```

Comment: try with this one

$classesAbsences = Classes::withSum(['absences' => function ($query) {
$query->selectRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `from`, `to`) AS hours_difference');
}], 'absences:hours_difference')->get();

Comment: still the same error : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'absences.absences:hours_difference' in 'field list'